# Excel VBA With Gift Card Web Site

Tags: excel, vba

Update: I'm redoing my question to hopefully make is simple to understand.

From the web site https://mygift.giftcardmall.com, I'm trying to find out how I can enter info for the "Card Number" box in the "Check Balance / Transactions" tab only.

I have tried `IE.Document.getElementByid("CardNumber").Value = "1234"` but this only enters the value on the "Card Number" box of the "Register Card" tab. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: DOM properties for element on both the tabs are same, so why don't you first click on desired tab and then enter the value...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish what I wanted with `IE.Document.getElementsByName("CardNumber")(1).Value = "1234"`. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use Microsoft's very own XMLHTTPRequest (may need to add a reference in VBA) to POST or PUT, otherwise you'll have to use the crappy `sendkeys` library to interact with websites.  XHR should work just fine for you.  Just google VBA XHR PUT.